# Understanding retry logic in the AWS PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

It seems that only the DynamoDB and S3Clients have [retry logic enabled](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%24args%5B%27retries%27%5D%5B%27fn%27%5D%20%3D%20&type=).

It seems like the `retries` config value has no effect on other services. Is there an easy way to enable this on others (e.g. SQS), or have I misunderstood this functionality?

I've located the `clientConfig.setUseThrottleRetries(true);` [option](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/introducing-retry-throttling/) in the Java SDK, but have yet to find an equivalent in the PHP SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood: SQS does have retries enabled.

To test: try the following:

```
$sqsClient = new sqqClient('2012-11-05', ['retries' => 2]);
$startTime = time();
try {
    $sqsClient->receiveMessages(['WaitTimeSeconds' => 5]);
} catch(Exception $e) {
}
$timeTaken = time() - $startTime;
echo $timeTaken;
```

and do not send any messages. You'll see

```
10
```

as that is `#WaitTime * #retries`

If you get no messages, it's considered a failure and will retry to get some.

S3 and DynamoDB have special cases - which is what you noticed.

Edit:

This works: hacking AWS code.

```
class final class Middleware
{

    public static function retry(
        callable $decider = null,
        callable $delay = null,
                 $stats = false
    ) {

    echo 'Forcing retries to false';
    $decider = function() {return false;};
    ...
```

This doesn't: in my code.

```
$decider = function() {
     echo 'No retries';
     return false;
};
$client->getHandlerList()->appendSign(\AWS\Middleware::retry($decider, null), 'retry');
```